# checking for NVRAM because of new installed graphics card

Tags: graphics

I installed new *msi graphics card* on my computer (motherboard has its own graphics card integrated). when I connect the monitor to the new graphics card it shows NO SIGNAL, but when I connect it with its own integrated graphics card it stucks at **CHECKING FOR NVRAM...** 
When I remove the new graphics card it works fine.

**UPDATE** 
hardware details: motherboard (ASRock 775Twins), new graphic card(MSI N210)

Comment: @Karan look at my update

Comment: I hope your PSU is powerful enough to handle the MSI card? Have you overclocked your system in any way? If so try undoing that, and also try resetting the BIOS back to defaults.

Comment: my PSU is also from MSI with 400W something like that.. and the graphics card requires PSU with more then 350W.  I am afraid to reset the BIOS because I have never done that and I dont know how to.

Comment: look up your mother board model, and you should find a manual, with instructions on how to reset your CMOS.

Comment: @FrankThomas is there a possibilty to mess up the bios and then not to start after I clear CMOS? because I need the computer for work? or is it normal and no harm comes from clearing CMOS?

Comment: in another forum someone said that the motherboard that I am using is hybrid and cant use 1gb graphics card, is it true?

Comment: no, there is almost no harm to resetting your CMOS. Flashing a BIOS has some risk involved, but resetting CMOS is not usually a cause for concern.

Comment: @FrankThomas Ok I will try that now and see if it solves the problem and then I will post the results

Comment: @FrankThomas I did clear CMOS, and the new graphics card works but it doesnt load windows it stucks on Checking NVRAM. after I cleared the cmos I entered setup and changed the time and date and nothing else. Should I do anything else?

Comment: in the bios, do you have an option to disable the integrated graphics chip? if so, disable it, and see if the NVRAM message goes away. otherwise I'd say the new card is damaged, or incompatible with your system.

Comment: No there not such option but now I think the computer doesnt recognize my HDD, because when the system starts its not like before and it is asking me to configure RAID BIOS setup utility with options like CREATE RAID 0 STRIPE x2 FOR PERFORMANCE, CREATE RAID 1 MIRRORING FOR RELIABIILITY etc.

Comment: unless you have a raid array, you should not need to worry about setting up the raid bios.

Comment: @FrankThomas hmmm I am having a really bad day, now the computer is messed up and wont start the windows, it goes till the logo of microsoft completes (stage: starting windows) and then restarts :(

Comment: have you tried removing the new card? also per the manual for your board, the primary monitor setting under Advanced -> Chipset configuration -> Northbridge configuration page. also in your other thread you mentioned you changed your ram. why?

Comment: FrankThomas  yes I removed the new card, I changed it because I thought that the problem with CHECKING NVRAM was with the RAM so I changed it but now in the bios it shows the RAM works fine I gave up I dont know what to do anymore! :(

Comment: NVRAM != RAM. sorry, I thought that was understood. NVRAM is the firmware on one of your graphics chips. I am thinking that your new card is damaged or incompatible, which is why you are getting that message. what we don't know is which graphics chip is causing the message. if its the integrated chip, which doesn't know what to do now that we've installed a discrete chip, then disabling it in bios is the solution. if its the new chip, and you had overclocked your hardware, then clearing the CMOS and disabling the integrated chip is the solution. since neither worked, I'd RMA the new card.